# Html style not displayed on my Qweb Report

Tags: html, report, odoo, odoo-12

I got a Qweb Report on `odoo11` that works perfectly ,but when i try adapting it on `odoo12`  the Html text loose it's style after adding `[url.report ,http:/0.0.0.0:8069]`

Here My Html field :

```
CGV_field = fields.Html(string="CGV", default=
        """<div><b>EXEMPLE DE CONDITIONS GENERALES DE VENTE</b></div>
        <div><b><br>\n</b></div>
        <b>Article 1 – Objet</b>
        <br>
        <p>Les présentes conditions régissent les ventes par la société (catégories ou nature des produits commercialisés par le site Internet).</p>
        <br>
        <b>Article 2 – Prix</b>
        <br>
        <p>Les prix de nos produits sont indiqués en Dinars toutes taxes comprises (TVA et autres taxes applicables au jour de la commande), sauf
        indication contraire et hors frais de traitement et d’expédition.
        Toutes les commandes quelle que soit leur origine sont payables en dinars.
        La société se réserve le droit de modifier ses prix à tout moment, mais le produit sera facturé sur la base du tarif en vigueur au moment de la
        validation de la commande et sous réserve de disponibilité.
        Les produits demeurent la propriété de la société jusqu’au paiement complet du prix.
        Attention : dès que vous prenez possession physiquement des produits commandés, les risques de perte ou d’endommagement des
        produits vous sont transférés.</p>"""
```

Calling it on xml report :

```
<template id="report_cgv_account">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="elosys_cgv_in_report.internal_layout_cgv_o">
                        <div class="page">
                            <div class="oe_structure"/>
                            <div class="row" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;">
                                <span style=" margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;" t-raw="o.company_id.CGV_field"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
```

what it's supposed to show :
[image: Odoo 11]

What i've got :
[image: Odoo12]

Comment: Can you provide further details on the question? How does elosys_cgv_in_report.internal_layout_cgv_o look like and what styles are applied?

Comment: i just did now , i noticed that the style goes off when i add [url.report ,http:/0.0.0.0:8069] to "Configurations/System parameters "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer if any of you wish to know :
just add `<![CDATA[&ensp;]]>` before `<span>`

Answer (score 2):

The System parameters key is `report.url` not `url.report`.